# Bash find where the current execution is located

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a shell program in a directory (ie dir1/dothis.sh) - works fine when I cd to that directory and ./dothis.sh

if I created a ln to that directoy  with a new name - dir2 and do dir2/dothis.sh
it would execute but it thinks the current execution path is the new dir where dir2 is pointing to at

in dothis.sh - how do I find where dothis.sh actually located?  The problem I have is that the dir1/dothis.sh can be relocated from system to system so there is no warranty where dir1/dothis.sh can be hard code

Comment: Please show us your code, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in

Answer (score 1):

Use the bash built-in

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Current path: $PWD"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
a=`pwd`
echo $a
b=$a"/"$0
echo `dirname $b`
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
dirname $(readlink -f $0)
```

It will also resolve symbolic link if any...